# Google Sheets data validation's input reject option is not working

Tags: validation, google-sheets

I have a google sheet something with 3 columns Column Name , Tech Club Name , Tech Club Email id . I want to have column `Tech Club Email id` to have unique entries . If someone tries to enter a duplicate entry it should reject it with an error message of `Entry already present` .

I have this data validation rule:
forumula: `=COUNTIF($C$2:$C10,$C2)<2`
[image]

Instead of the formula whenever I enter duplicate entry in the column it doesn't reject the input it only gives warning on the previous input as shown below:

[image]

How can have a data validation rule which simply rejects user from entering the duplicate value ?

Comment: select your desired range and update formula in data validation as `=countif($C$2:C2,C2)=1`

Comment: @DevenRamani your solution somewhat worked but I am not able to enter any new unique entry now

Answer (score 1):

The cell range entered in the Data Validation Box should not be the whole column (which contains 1000 rows), but rather a more limited range. If you want to check between the `C2` and `C10` cells, I would suggest changing the cell range from:

```
Sheet1!C1:C1000
```

to:

```
Sheet1!C2:C10
```

although you can choose a wider range if you want, it just cannot be the whole column.